# Insert Items on List Control on specific Row in MFC

Tags: c++, list, mfc

Ive made a MFC program where I got a List Control (Report View). I want wo insert Items on a specific Row. So with

```
m_List.InsertItem (...)
```

I dont really know where I can define that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The documentation for MFC's CListCtrl ListView Common Control wrapper, and specifically the `InsertItem` member, can be found [at this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b9s12fc(v=vs.90).aspx), the general class [at this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78(v=vs.90).aspx), the ListView common control documentation [at this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff485973(v=vs.85).aspx), and common controls in-general [at this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773169(v=vs.85).aspx). They're ***all*** worth the read for learning common controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a report view, an item is the representation of a row.
Columns must be added to accept so called sub-items.
You insert data into sub-Items with [LVM_SETITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
All this info is perfectly documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)